# Drilldown operation in Column-Stacked Bar diagram HighCharts

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts, jinja2

I have a bar diagram something similar to this

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked/

And I need to display a drill-down in such a way that a single column is split into multiple bars in the next page.

For example:
If I click Apples column in the bar, it should drill down into the next page with 3 columns

- First Column  - x-Axis: Joe, y-Axis: 3
- Second Column - x-Axis: Jane, y-Axis: 2
- Third Column - x-Axis: John, y-Axis: 5

Similar operations for the rest of the columns in the main bar diagram.
Finally, I should be able to navigate back to the main page as well.

Any help from anyone would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked column chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: ( // theme
                    Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style &&
                    Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style.color
                ) || 'gray'
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -30,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor:
            Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || 'white',
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        borderWidth: 1,
        shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <p class="highcharts-description">
        Chart showing stacked columns for comparing quantities. Stacked charts
        are often used to visualize data that accumulates to a sum. This chart
        is showing data labels for each individual section of the stack.
    </p>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement is possible to achieve by config data in the proper way and adding drilldown module.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xz46uspb/

Series data example:

```
  series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [{
      y: 5,
      name: 'Apples',
      drilldown: "Apples"
    }, {
      y: 3,
      name: 'Oranges',
      drilldown: "Oranges"
    }, {
      y: 4,
      name: 'Pears',
      drilldown: "Pears"
    }]
  }, ...
],
```

And drilldown data:

```
  drilldown: {
    series: [{
      name: 'Apples',
      id: 'Apples',
      colorByPoint: true,
      data: [{
        name: 'John',
        y: 5
      }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        y: 2
      }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        y: 3
      }]
    }]
  }
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.colorByPoint

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/drilldown